# In Google Sheets, how can paste a copied cell/value into several selected cells at once?

Tags: google-sheets

What I need to do is to first copy a cell (or the value of the cell), then select a number of other cells (not necessarily in a continuous range), then I want to paste that cell or value into all the selected cells *at once*.

What happens is the value gets pasted only into the first selected cell, and not to any of the others.

How can I do this?

I'm not super familiar with the intricacies of this product. I've tried searching, but maybe I'm not very good at it because I couldn't find anyone with the same problem exactly.

Comment: you want to repaste formulas?

Comment: No, simple text context.

Comment: I mean "content".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## method 1:

- select desired cell
- press **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>ARROW KEY</kbd>**

  - or **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>ARROW KEY</kbd>**
- and then **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

## method 2:

- select desired cell
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**
- then select multiple cells where you want to paste by holding **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>**

  - or **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>** for **values** only
  - or **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>ALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>** for **format** only
  - for more options see image

[image]

Comment: There should be more upvotes on this answer.  It worked for me on July 18, 2020, on Ubuntu 16, Chromium 81.0,4044.138.  So it should work for almost anyone on Windows, probably Mac too.  Unless you're using IE or Netscape classic, or maybe Opera?  (something really rarely used) .  Please **upvote** _unless_ it didn't work for you!

Comment: For Method 1, Command-Enter worked for me on OS X (instead of Ctrl-Enter)